# Converting Rotational Inertia into Linear Equivalent Mass

Tags: classical-mechanics, moment-of-inertia

I am working on a dynamic model of a very simple "lever" system, consisting of a solid body pivoting around a point, and a linear actuator acting on the body making it rotate around such pivot. (Sketched it up in GeoGebra [here](https://ggbm.at/evqqWTSK). A slider at the top controls movement.)

I have determined the dynamics of the system follow an equation of the form:
$$J\cdot \ddot\theta = M(x)$$
Where $J$ is the moment of inertia of the body around the pivot, $\theta$ is the rotation angle around the pivot and $M(x)$ is the moment applied on the body as a function of $x$, the extension of the actuator. All of these variables are known as functions of $x$.

My question is, how do I turn this equation into an equation of the form:
$$m_{eq}\cdot\ddot x = F(x)$$
Where $m_{eq}$ is an equivalent mass (possibly function of $x$) and $F(x)$ is the force exerted by the actuator (known).

Can I simply do a transformation of the form $J=m_{eq}\cdot r^2$ where $r$ is the distance from the pivot to the point where the actuator applies force (always constant)?

Comment: Why do you want to convert it to Newton's 2nd law? The first equation already has the same mathematical form as Newton's law with mass replaced by moment of inertia, position by angle and force by torque. This was also the reason why these concepts of rotational movement were introduced in the first place.

Comment: Because I will be running this is for an actual application. A Control System will be designed around the linear actuator, hence wanting to have everything as a function of $x$, the extension of the actuator.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I simply do a transformation of the form $J=meq⋅r2$ where $r$ is the distance from the pivot to the point where the actuator applies force (always constant)?

Unfortunately it's far from *that simple*.

[image: Actuator extended]

Look at the geometry **with the actuator extended** (above). Note my definition of $\theta$ and that $|P'P|=r$. The actuator force $F$ does not act perpendicularly to $OP$ and the 'useful' moment about $O$ is only:

$$\tau=F\times |OP| \times \cos\theta$$

Now look at the geometry **without the actuator extended** (below), where $|P'P|=0$, that is $|O'P|=r_0$:

[image: Actuator not extended]

Because $OPO'$ is a right angled triangle:

$$|OO'|^2=r_0^2+|OP|^2$$

[Using the trigonometry of non right angled triangles](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/reference/chpt-5/non-right-triangle-trigonometry/):

$$|OO'|^2=|O'P|^2+|OP|^2-2|O'P||OP|\cos\theta$$
$$\cos\theta=\frac{|O'P|^2+|OP|^2-|OO'|^2}{2|O'P||OP|}$$
$$\cos\theta=\frac{(r+r_0)^2+|OP|^2-r_0^2-|OP|^2}{2r_0|OP|}$$
$$\cos\theta=\frac{r^2+2rr_0}{2r_0|OP|}$$
So that:
$$\tau=F\frac{r^2+2rr_0}{2r_0}$$
The *angular acceleration* $\alpha=\dot{\omega}$ of the solid body is then given by:

$$\tau=I\alpha$$
Where $I$ is the moment of inertia of the solid body *about* the point $O$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple geometric relationship for planar mechanics for the effective mass a force sees. Below I show the relationship between an applied force $F$ and the acceleration of the body along the line of action of the force $\ddot{x}$.

Consider the two cases below:

[image: sketch]

1. A pinned object about point *A*, with distance $c$ from the pivot to the center of mass, and $d$ from the pivot to the *line of action* of the force $F_P$.

   $$ F_P = \left( \frac{I_C + m c^2}{d^2}  \right)  \ddot{x}_P =\left( \frac{I_A }{d^2}  \right)  \ddot{x}_P $$

   <sub>$I_C$ is the mass moment of inertia about *C*, and $I_A$ about *A*.</sub>
2. A sliding object along point *A*, with angle $\psi$ to the *line of action* of the force $F_P$.

   $$ F_P = \left( \frac{m}{\cos(\psi)^2}  \right) \ddot{x}_P  $$

The stuff inside the parenthesis is the *effective* linear mass along the force line of action. As a check, you can see that if $d=0$ the mass is infinite since the force is acting against the pivot. Similarly when the body is sliding perpendicularly to the force and $\psi = \tfrac{\pi}{2}$.